# One single ASM instruction for a given sequence

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I need to write the following sequence as one single ASM instruction, but I don't know what instruction it is:

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
mov ebp,[ebp]
mov ebx,[ebp]
mov [esp],ebx
```

Comment: Clearly we need a `push` or equivalent and also `ebx` needs to be set. I don't think a single instruction can do that.  Are you sure you copied it correctly? Two instructions would be `mov ebx, [ebp]; push ebx`. `ebp` is not changed by that sequence so that can be ignored.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment or some kind of study question can you post the exact question you were given. If this isn't an academic question what problem are you really trying to solve. I'm with @Jester, this would take 2 instructions to do, although there is more than one way to achieve the same result.

Comment: The first 3 instructions push EBP, then reload the just-saved EBP value into EBP.  So the net effect of the first 3 is `lea esp, [esp-4]` (not SUB, because that would affect FLAGS).  Assuming that no other threads are modifying the memory where we stored/reloaded EBP, of course, otherwise the store/reload might not always reload the same value!  We do eventually store to `[esp]`, so optimizing away some of the memory access doesn't change the behaviour of faulting if ESP is pointing to memory that isn't readable and writeable.

Comment: @PeterCordes : A side effect of these instructions is that EBX is also being modified to contain what EBP was pointing to. So to get the exact behavior of these instruction EBX will have to be modified. It is funny that you are concerned about modifying the flags register but don't be concerned about modifying EBX.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I know, but I was only talking about the first 3.  I suspect this question is total garbage, and isn't counting the EBX side-effect, and they're looking for `push [ebp]`.  (If we also assume that the original EBP value wasn't pointing to ESP-4.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : Which of course is why I asked for the exact wording of the question given him if this was an academic problem. I do not know what assumptions we can make, but maybe if we had the exact question we might know. Why assume, when we can ask the OP for clarification?

Comment: There's always the `ENTER` instruction that can do a bunch of wacky stuff to setup a stack frame in a single instruction...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: yeah, I thought of ENTER, but it doesn't modify EBX, and the crap this does with EBP actually cancels out (if `[ebp]` doesn't overlap the push  destination.)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I posted an answer with a detailed analysis of what this does, including EBX and the possible overlap of `[ebp]` and the `push` destination.

Comment: @Jester: Your 2 instruction sequence isn't equivalent if there was a `lea ebp, [esp-1..7]` or equivalent sometime before this sequence.  I put a commented version in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**It's impossible to reproduce all the behaviour exactly for all input values with 1 or even 2 instructions.**

---

The first 3 instructions push EBP, then reload the just-saved EBP value into EBP.  So the net effect of the first 3 is `lea esp, [esp-4]` (not SUB, because that would affect FLAGS)<sup>1</sup>.

```
push ebp          ; save old EBP,  ESP-=4

mov ebp,esp 
mov ebp,[ebp]     ; reload old EBP
;; net effects so far: ESP-=4.
;;                     memory at [ESP] replaced with old-EBP.

mov ebx,[ebp]     ; EBX = [EBP].  This could overlap with dword [ESP]

mov [esp],ebx     ; replace pushed original_EBP value with [original_EBP]
```

**I suspect they answer they're looking for might be `push [ebp]`, but if so this question is total garbage.**  There are 2 key side-effects that doesn't reproduce:

- It doesn't leave the `[EBP]` value in EBX
- It's not the same if `[EBP]` (partially) overlaps with `[ESP-4]`

To reproduce the set-EBX behaviour, you need at least 2 instructions.  x86 has some complex instructions, but none that push memory *and* copy to an integer register.  **Jester's 2-instruction sequence looks closest: `mov   ebx, [ebp]` / `push  ebx`**.

You could also consider `push dword [ebp]` / `mov ebx, [esp]`, but that's obviously less efficient, and stores/reloads the `[ebp]` value unlike the given sequence.

But neither of those reproduce the exact behaviour if `[ebp]` overlaps the push destination.  e.g. consider `lea ebp, [esp-2]` before those instructions.  **The given sequence does a store of EBP before loading `[ebp]`, and nothing tells us that there isn't overlap.**  If you were using EBP as a frame pointer, normally it wouldn't be pointing below ESP, but we aren't told that.

---

---

Footnote 1:  **Assuming that no other threads are modifying the memory where we stored/reloaded EBP**, of course, otherwise the store/reload might not always reload the same value!  We do eventually store to `[esp]`, so optimizing away some of the memory access doesn't change the behaviour of faulting if ESP is pointing to memory that isn't readable and writeable.

Nothing in the question says I get to make *any* assumptions about where ESP is pointing, or what else might be happening asynchronously to that memory location.

For all we know, ESP is pointing to an MMIO region, and every store / load has a visible side-effect like putting the bits on the pins of a parallel port, or reading them!

In a normal context where ESP is pointing to read+writeable memory in a write-back region that no other threads have a reference to, then optimizing away stores/reloads is valid.  But like I said, nothing says we get to assume that.